# Cannot insert NULL values into column 'USERNAME', table 'tempdb.dbo.#temptable error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have a SP. while executing I am getting error as

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'USERNAME', table 'tempdb.dbo.#temptable__________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000002FD'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Below is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserReportData] 
                @As_ONDATE Datetime 

                AS 
            BEGIN 
                    DECLARE @REPORTDATE datetime        
                    DECLARE @USERNAME varchar(110)      

            Select * INTO #temptable
        FROM
                    (
                        select  a.CUser_id, b.User_Id, a.U_datetime
                        as REPORTDATE, b.first_Name + ' '  + b.last_name as USERNAME
                        from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join user_mst b
                        on a.CUser_id = b.mkey
                        and a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE
                ) as x

DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR
            FOR SELECT CUser_id, User_Id FROM #temptable

                    OPEN Cur_1
                        DECLARE @CUser_id INT
                        DECLARE @User_Id INT
                        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 
                        INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id

                        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN

                            SELECT @REPORTDATE = U_datetime FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl                        
                            where  U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE                             



                            UPDATE #temptable
                                SET REPORTDATE = @REPORTDATE,
                                    USERNAME = @USERNAME
                                WHERE CUser_id = @CUser_id
                                AND User_Id = @User_Id  


                FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id
                    END
            CLOSE Cur_1
            DEALLOCATE Cur_1


            SELECT * FROM #temptable
                        DROP TABLE #temptable                           
    END
```

**UPDATED PROCEDURE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserReportData] 
                @As_ONDATE Datetime 

                AS 
            BEGIN 
                    DECLARE @REPORTDATE datetime        
                    DECLARE @USERNAME varchar(110)      

            Select * INTO #temptable
        FROM
                    (
                        select  a.CUser_id, b.User_Id, a.U_datetime
                        as REPORTDATE, ISNULL(b.first_Name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') AS USERNAME                         
                        from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join user_mst b
                        on a.CUser_id = b.mkey
                        and a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE
                ) as x

DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR
            FOR SELECT CUser_id, User_Id FROM #temptable

                    OPEN Cur_1
                        DECLARE @CUser_id INT
                        DECLARE @User_Id INT
                        --DECLARE @USERNAME VARCHAR (100)
                        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 
                        INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id

                        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN

                            SELECT @REPORTDATE = U_datetime FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl                        
                            where  U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE 

                            SELECT @USERNAME = ISNULL(b.first_Name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') 
                                FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl a 
                                INNER JOIN user_mst b on a.CUser_id = b.mkey 
                                where a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE                            

                            UPDATE #temptable
                                SET REPORTDATE = @REPORTDATE,
                                    USERNAME = @USERNAME
                                WHERE CUser_id = @CUser_id
                                AND User_Id = @User_Id  


                FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id
                    END
            CLOSE Cur_1
            DEALLOCATE Cur_1


            SELECT * FROM #temptable
                        DROP TABLE #temptable                           
    END
```

Comment: You didn't SET ant value to `@USERNAME`

Comment: @Arulkumar: yes but how to set it

Comment: same as other cursor variables

Comment: @Arulkumar: while setting the value i am getting error as `Incorrect syntax near 'USERNAME'.` here is what i tried `SELECT @USERNAME =  b.first_Name + ' '  + b.last_name  USERNAME
         from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join user_mst b
         on a.CUser_id = b.mkey
           and  a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE`

Comment: @IvanStarostin: I tried like above, but getting error as `Incorrect syntax near 'USERNAME'.`

Comment: Each sp version does not make any sense at all. Try to read aloud what is going on before cursor opening and inside loop. Update your questoin: describe what's stored in your tables and what outcome you're attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment the @USERNAME declaration in the initial `BEGIN` block

```
 -- DECLARE @USERNAME varchar(110)
```

then handle the `NULL` value for the `USERNAME` as in the `SELECT * INTO` block

```
 ISNULL(b.first_Name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') AS USERNAME
```

Then add the `@USERNAME` in the CURSOR as

```
DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR
        FOR SELECT CUser_id, User_Id, USERNAME FROM #temptable

            OPEN Cur_1
                    DECLARE @CUser_id INT
                    DECLARE @User_Id INT
                    DECLARE @USERNAME VARCHAR (200) -- can set your required length
                    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 
                    INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id
```

Then the `@USERNAME` won't throw the `NULL` error

---

**UPDATE**: Based on your comments, I updated the answer:

So you want to get the `@USERNAME` based on the `U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE` condition.

So use your existing code and add one more block inside the CURSOR for getting the `@USERNAME` value as after the `SELECT @REPORTDATE = U_datetime FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl where  U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE`

```
SELECT @USERNAME = ISNULL(b.first_Name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') -- no need of column alias here
FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl a 
INNER JOIN user_mst b on a.CUser_id = b.mkey 
WHERE a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE
```

Comment: Please check the *UPDATE* answer

Comment: yes, it worked with no error. but all rows coming same USERNAME.

Comment: Can you post your recent code in the question. It may be a typo after update the coe.

Comment: Updated code is correct, you are using same condition for all the @USERNAME, so obviously all those have same value, if you want to get @USERNAME based on your `CUser_id`, `User_id` add those values in the `WHERE` clause like `WHERE a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE AND a.CUser_id = @CUser_id AND b.User_id = @User_id`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserReportData] 
@As_ONDATE Datetime 

AS 
BEGIN 
    Select * INTO #temptable
    FROM
    (
        select  
            a.CUser_id, 
            b.User_Id, 
            a.U_datetime as REPORTDATE, 
            ISNULL( b.first_Name + ' '  + b.last_name, 'NONAME' ) as USERNAME -- normally if one of the two is null then all of it is Null
        from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join user_mst b
        on a.CUser_id = b.mkey
        and a.U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE
    ) as x



    DECLARE @REPORTDATE datetime 

    -- moved out of the loop
    SELECT @REPORTDATE = U_datetime 
    FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl                        
    where  U_datetime >= @As_ONDATE -- this might bring more than one rows I think ???????


    DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CUser_id, User_Id, USERNAME FROM #temptable
    DECLARE @CUser_id INT
    DECLARE @User_Id INT    
    DECLARE @USERNAME varchar(110) 

    OPEN Cur_1    
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id, @USERNAME

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE #temptable SET 
            REPORTDATE = @REPORTDATE,
            USERNAME =  @USERNAME
        WHERE 
            CUser_id = @CUser_id
            AND User_Id = @User_Id  

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id, @USERNAME

    END

    CLOSE Cur_1
    DEALLOCATE Cur_1

    SELECT * FROM #temptable
    DROP TABLE #temptable                           
END
```