# How to run LOOP in a cursor for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SP, which gives me two records (2 username) like below

[image: SP loop]

Now,

> what I want is to loop each user using `cursor` and display its data from the table for the date which is passed as in the parameter

Below is my SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_USER_REPORT_DATA
        @From_Date datetime,
        @To_Date datetime

    AS
    BEGIN

        Select * into #GetUserTable
            from
                (
                      select distinct a.N_UserMkey, b.mkey,   
                      b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join user_mst b on 
                      a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey 
                      where a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date                  
                ) as xx     

    DECLARE @N_Usermkey int, @mkey int, @NAME varchar       
        DECLARE UserCursor CURSOR FOR  
            select distinct a.N_UserMkey, b.mkey,   
                      b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME from inward_doc_tracking_trl a inner join
                      user_mst b on a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey 
                      where a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date
        OPEN UserCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
            INTO @N_Usermkey, @mkey, @NAME 

        -- need to run loop for each user

            SELECT * FROM #GetUserTable
                         DROP TABLE #GetUserTable
    END
```

GO

I am unaware on how to use `cursor` kindly let me know

Comment: This logic doesn't require the use of a cursor.  You should only use cursors when they are necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: so without cursor, how it is possible to loop each user with all the relevant data with respective to its `mkey`  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot insert NULL values into column 'USERNAME', table 'tempdb.dbo.#temptable error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760849/cannot-insert-null-values-into-column-username-table-tempdb-dbo-temptable-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a cursor for this at all your simple select query should be enough ...

```
select  a.N_UserMkey
       ,b.mkey
       ,ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ','') + ISNULL(b.last_name,'') NAME 
from inward_doc_tracking_trl a 
inner join user_mst b on a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey 
where a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date
```

Comment: thanks, but I have already used that in my temp table which gives me the respective records. But can u tell me how to proceed that with cursor for looping each user to check whether records for the date which is passed exist or not

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is already doing this, you DO NOT NEED a cursor for it.

Comment: yes u r right.will confirm with my senior and Will continue tomorrow. Need to go for prayer. bye tc

Comment: @NK If you need to confirm answers you get from here with someone, shouldn't you just ask him the first place?